# Separating Numerical String Values

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a numerical string that needs a space inserted between 0 and 9999.

**Command:**

```
echo "9999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.0" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]\s/g'
```

**Desired Output:**

```
9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Hubert. Initially, I tried using `sed` to match a pattern of `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]` but, this did not work.

Comment: So do you need to match arbitrary numbers or is it always 09999? Your question doesn't say anything about the input except one example.

Comment: The input will always be the original string (e.g. "9999.09999.09999.09999.099...")

Comment: Search for "09" and make it "0 9" then. My answer does exactly that using sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really little detail you're giving us here...

```
echo "9999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.09999.0" | sed "s/09/0 9/g"

9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0 9999.0
```

Comment: Perfect! It appears that I was over-thinking my approach.